# How do I perform in-app audio processing using python on an audio that I record with an android app?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite, audio-processing

I have a python code that processes audio and classifies it into two groups.

The python code uses **vgg16 model** 
The model is saved in a **'.json'** file and the weights are saved in **'.hdf5'** file format

I have built an app that records audio and saves it in the local storage of the phone.

I want to perform in-app processing on the recorded audio using my python code to perform classification.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question needs more focus. What have you tried yourself? Where exactly are you stuck in your own attempt?

Comment: can you entertain the possibility of having the app talk to your server side where the python lives ... or are you trying to execute the python on the mobile side

Comment: Thank you Pete and Scott. To reply Scott, I am ready to try both approaches. I watched youtube videos where in the first approach the video shows how to create a ".pb" file for model and run it in the app itself. Another approach was to deploy the code on server side and perform the audio processing there and get back results. I am interested in the client-server approach. But I'd like to learn both so anything can do.